# PHP mysqli prepared UPDATE statement inserts the wrong values

Tags: php, mysql

I really hope I'm not missing something obvious here, all the parameter orders look fine to me but the *name* value gets updated to 0 while the *description* value is not touched.

The function:

```
public function doEdit ($user_id, $conn, $list_name, $list_desc, $list_id) {

   echo "user id: " . $user_id . ", list id: " . $list_id 
       . ", list name: " . $list_name . ", list desc: " . $list_desc;

   if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE collection.user_list SET name = ? 
          AND description = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND list_id = ?"))) {
      echo "Prepare failed: " . $mysqli->error;
   }
   if (!($stmt->bind_param('ssii', $list_name, $list_desc, $user_id, 
          $list_id))) {
      echo "Bind failed: " . $stmt->error;
   }
   if (!($stmt->execute())) {
      echo "Execute failed: " . $stmt->error;
   }
 }
```

The call:

```
if ($req == "PUT") {
   parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_PUT);
   $this->doEdit($user_id, $conn, $_PUT['Name'], $_PUT['Description'],
           $_PUT['ListID']);
}
```

I get no failure notifications and on a runthrough the variable echo gives
`user id: 1, list id: 9, list name: edited name, list desc: edited description`

but the db row is changed from:

```
user_id, list_id, name, description
'1', '9', 'hello', 'world'
```

to:

```
user_id, list_id, name, description
'1', '9', '0', 'world'
```

What am I missing/messing up?

Comment: Nope, all the parameter orders do not look fine. It's rather a mess

Comment: SET uses commas not AND

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, that's it, can't believe it was something so silly!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah, I appreciate that, I've spent 12 hours trying to get things working and understand them before I even approach refactoring - apologies for submitting such mess